# Pixelated Markers only in IE11

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-11

I'm using Gmaps plugin on google maps. Take a look at the code below and the explanation. I've tried many possible answers but nothing seems to work.

```
var facility = new google.maps.MarkerImage("facility-pin.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(28,28));

map.addMarker({
    lat: 50.445619,
    lng: -104.708681,
    title: 'Marker with InfoWindow',
    icon: facility,
    optimized: false, 
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  });
```

This code places a marker at the right location and instead of the typical google marker, it's my custom pin. The original image size is 1000px x 1000px. The issue I'm having is with the line "optimized: false". When I open this on Google Chrome. the icon looks like the image below (what I want):

[image]

But if I open this map on Internet Explorer 11 the pin is all pixelated like this:

[image]

I don't understand why it's doing this. I originally had the icon all pixelated on Google Chrome but adding the optimized line fixed it. Unfortunately it didn't fix the issue on IE11. Does IE read the code differently or is there a code I'm missing? I tried looking through the documentation but couldn't find any solutions. Has anyone had similar issues?

TYIA

Comment: Does it work better if you don't scale the marker down so much?

Comment: It's still pixelated. I've tried using the original image size as 56x56 and it didn't change.

Comment: Also, The marker size (28x28) is the size I want it to be on the map. I can't figure out why optimized:false works on Chrome but not IE?

Comment: IE being different from other browsers is not surprising at all.  Microsoft never made "standard" browsers (although they are getting better...)

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix this? I need the map to work on IE more than anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue. The line below is what I was using but I converted the facility-pin.png to an SVG file and it works perfectly. So apparently IE11 doesn't listen to the "optimized: false" line but can scale down SVG without a problem.

```
var facility = new google.maps.MarkerImage("facility-pin.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(28,28));
```